# Transfer data from json files in S3 to RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I have many json files located in S3. I need to take each file, extract the relevant information, and insert the data into various tables in mySQL database I have in Amazon RDS. What is the best way to do this? The files are arriving constantly so I need this service to run all the time - taking files, parsing them and inserting data to the database.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need an EC2 instance that runs 24x7 polling for files on S3 and doing the required work.

How big that instance should be, or even how many of them you might deploy is dependent on the volume of files you are getting, and how quickly they must be processed.

If this was me, I'd write the processing job in C# as a console app, spin up one or more ec2 instances and then schedule the job with task scheduler.

If windows/.net is not your platform of choice, you can do the equivalent on a Linux box using the language and scheduling tool of your choice.

If this is going to run for a long time (i.e. months or more), consider purchasing a reserved instance and you will save quite a bit of money over an on-demand one.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/